# Rebooting grub once without timer

Tags: grub2, reboot

I want to reboot into Windows directly per command, I know that I can change the preselected OS once via `grub-reboot X`, where as `X` is the index of the selected OS. But is it possible to also set the waiting timer to 0 just for one reboot?